# How solve error expected ;

Tags: java

Given an integer,n , perform the following conditional actions:

If n,  is odd, print Weird
If n, is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
If n, is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

My Code is

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.math.*;
    import java.util.regex.*;

    public class Solution {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int n=sc.nextInt();            
            String ans="";
            if(n%2==1)  {
              ans = "Weird";
            }

            elseif(n%2==0 && 2<=n<=5){
                ans = "Not Weird";
            }

            elseif(n%2==0 && 6<=n<=20) {
                ans = "Weird";
            }

            elseif(n>=20)
            {
             ans = "Weird";``

            }
            System.out.println(ans);

        }
    }
```

And there are error :
Solution.java:18: error: ';' expected
            elseif(n%2==0 && 2<=n<=5){
                                     ^
Solution.java:22: error: ';' expected
            elseif(n%2==0 && 6<=n<=20) {
                                      ^
Solution.java:26: error: ';' expected
            elseif(n>=20)
                         ^
3 errors
I don't know how to solve those problem.

Comment: `2<=n<=5` is also not Java style

Comment: And there's the fact that `elseif` is not a Java keyword, and random backticks at the ends of lines are not just going to be ignored by the compiler.. I suggest reviewing some basic Java tutorials/books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2<=n<=5` is not a legal Java expression, and neither is the keyword `elseif`. You should use `2 <= n && n <= 5`, and `else if`